# returning local struct in a function

Tags: c++, function, memory-management, local

im trying to return a local variable from a function.

```cpp
typedef struct _s{
  int a;
} Somestruct;

Somestruct func(){
  Somestruct RET;
  RET.a = 10;
}

int main(){

  Somestruct var = func();
  std::cout << var.a();
}
```

will this work? if i doesnt, what do i need to do to make it return the value i want?
i have tried to do this with classes but it doesnt work. From the info i have learnt, when i return classes it just returns the pointer that points to the memory. However, i was thinking if i did structs, then it would physically return the whole data, not just a reference or pointer.

Comment: Where in `func` do you `return` anything?

Comment: sorry, a mistake, i meant to return something

Comment: "From the info i have learnt, when i return classes it just returns the pointer that points to the memory." That is wrong. When you return an object then an object is returned, not a pointer

Comment: No it doesn't return a pointer. In most cases the compiler will actually know it should allocate the object at the caller, and then let the function fill it. 
The details are described here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: Looks like you are learning C++ after learning C.  Change this C-style type `typedef struct _s { int a; } Somestruct;` to C++ `struct Somestruct { int a; };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *what do i need to do to make it return the value i want?*

You need to literally ask the program to do that using `return RET;`

```
typedef struct _s{
  int a;
} Somestruct;

Somestruct func(){
  Somestruct RET;
  RET.a = 10;
  return RET;  // <====
}
```

> *when i return classes it just returns the pointer that points to the memory*

No, C++ has [value semantics](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/value-vs-ref-semantics#val-vs-ref-semantics). Returning a struct/class by-value will return the struct itself.

There is no difference between a struct and a class with this respect.

---

Bonus note: `var.a()` is not a function, you probably want `var.a`.

```
int main(){

  Somestruct var = func();
  std::cout << var.a << "\n";  // <====
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> will this work?

No. There are severe issues:

- Function has been declared to return an object, but there is no return statement (nor a throw nor anything that would terminate the program). The behaviour of the program is undefined.
- `_s::a` is not callable, so `var.a()` is ill-formed.
- The identifier `_s` is reserved to the language implementation in the global namespace. By defining it, the behaviour will be undefined.

> what do i need to do to make it return the value i want?

A return statement.

> From the info i have learnt, when i return classes it just returns the pointer that points to the memory.

You've learned wrong. When you return instance of a class, you return a copy of the value (this is somewhat simplified description for the benefit of a beginner reader).

> However, i was thinking if i did structs

Structs are classes too.

Comment: Further explanation of the problem with `_s`: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Answer (score 1):

It works if you modify func() like so:

```
Somestruct func(){
  Somestruct RET;
  RET.a = 10;
  return RET;
}
```

For your second point, you can definitely return classes, you just have to be careful to return the actual object like this `myClass myFunc()` and not through a pointer `myClass* myFunc()` nor through a reference `myClass& myFunc()`